# Compute the limit of the sequence given by bn =(1+(3.4/n))^n

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If a sequence  $c_1$ , $c_2$ , $c_3$ ,... $c_{n-1}$, $c_n$, $c_{n+1}$,... has limit $K$ then the sequence $e^{c_1}$, $e^{c_2}$, $e^{c_3}$ , ... $e^{c_{n-1}}$, $e^{c_n}$, $e^{c_{n+1}}$,... has limit  $e^K$. Use this fact together with l'Hopital's rule to compute the limit of the sequence given by $$b_n =\bigg(1+\frac{3.4}{n}\bigg)^n $$

Answer (score 2):

Making the problem more general, consider $$b_n =\bigg(1+\frac{a}{n}\bigg)^n$$ Take logarithms $$\log(b_n)=n\log\bigg(1+\frac{a}{n}\bigg)=\frac{\log\bigg(1+\frac{a}{n}\bigg)}{\frac 1n}$$ Define $x=\frac 1n$ which makes $$\log(b_n)=\frac{\log\bigg(1+ax \bigg)}{x}$$ which is, at the limit $\frac 0 0$. Use  L'Hopital's rule $$u=\log\bigg(1+ax \bigg)\implies u'=\frac a {1+a x}\qquad , \qquad v=x\implies v'=1$$ So $$\frac u v=\frac {u'}{v'}=\frac a {1+a x}\to a$$ So, $\log(b_n)\to a \implies b_n=e^a$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for as it does not use the given information but just the definition of the exponential function:

The limit definition of the exponential function is:

$$
e^x=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n
$$
As you have defined:
$$
b_n=\left(1+\frac{3.4}{n} \right)^n
$$
the limit as $n\to \infty$ of $b_n$ is $e^{3.4}$